# Typescript does not notice that a Partial<Record<...>> key may not exist if there are required keys

Tags: typescript, types

After defining a type to describe an object with required and with optional keys along the lines of

```js
type ItemWithOptionals<OPTIONAL extends string, REQUIRED extends string> =
   Partial<Record<OPTIONAL, string>> & Record<REQUIRED, string>;
```

the compiler does not conclude that an access with a key of type `OPTIONAL` may return `undefined`, as in

```js
function wantString(text: string): void { ... }

function f2<O extends string, R extends string>(opt: O, rec: ItemWithOptionals<O, R>): void {
  const x = rec[opt];
  wantString(x);
}
```

It seems to be obvious that `rec[opt]` may return `undefined`, but the call to `wantString(x)` is not marked as an error. And the type assist for `x` doesn't show `undefined` either ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSNgFsDqBLGACwHkwY8IA7AQwBsBnAHmIAUAVNYgOQEEAZOKEyUAJvTj0YUPJQDmAGjgAlAKIBFAKppVAEUEhhYiVJmyAfHAC8AKBbVYeOoyXAAxtBHN2nXn0WTpOTMLADJlNw9ndS1dfxMggG5rawAzAFdKV3IqOAB3akoYAGV42QAKTAMALmNA2QBKGoA3CDwROABvazgeuHdKeghaYAA6WghygHIiVADTODxxSbgAagQheqSAX2T0zOzKOBSAJmZ9Q3E5uUUlc%20BRS9KzMogyGuJFKDcajGx8IlIBzoTA%20yjMjTgLTanW6fSokjgICscC%20rgA2q8YABdJI9fKFEp1MogTbWHZAA)).

Why does the compiler not derive that `undefined` is part of the type of `x`? Can the type of `ItemWithOptionals` be improved to let the compiler notice this?

Comment: you need `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in tsconfig, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true

Comment: @Dimava No, that setting doesn't fix it.  Did you try?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a TS design limitation or bug but I haven't found an existing report.  Looks like intersections of generic mapped types has a type hole in it, probably to allow for ease of use, but it has this side effect.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAd7XN) for another instance of it (without partial/undefined).  If I can't find a relevant GitHub issue I might file one, just to find out what the official word is

Comment: Looking into this more, I think this is the same issue as [ms/TS#33181](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181); generic property reads are checked by widening generics to their constraint. In this case, `O` and `R` get widened to `string` and so `ItemWithOptionals<O, R>` is (unsoundly) converted to `Partial<Record<string, string>> & Record<string, string>`, equivalent to `Record<string, string>`.  For a workaround you could manually widen soundly, like [this](//tsplay.dev/weB0eN). ...

Comment: ... Does this fully address your question? If so, I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in a comment if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Yes it does, in particular why this does not work as I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181) for more information.

There is a trade-off between accuracy and convenience when it comes to analyzing [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types like `ItemWithOptionals<O, R>[O]`, the type of `rec[opt]`.  Either the compiler can *defer* analysis and keep the type generic and accurate but mostly unexamined, in which case the type is essentially opaque and can't easily be used, or it can *eagerly* analyze the type by widening the generic type parameters to their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which turns it into a specific type that can be used easily, but which might not be accurate.

Generally, when you read a property like `rec[opt]` where the types are generic, the compiler will tend to do the possibly-inaccurate but convenient widening.  In this case, `rec` is of type `ItemWithOptionals<O, R>`, where `O` and `R` are both constrained to `string`.

The widening results in `ItemWithOptionals<string, string>`, which evaluates to `Partial<Record<string, string>> & Record<string, string>`, which in turn evaluates to `Record<string, string | undefined> & Record<string, string>`, which is equivalent to just `Record<string, string>` (since all of the properties are the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `(string | undefined) & string` which evaluates to `string`), or `{[k: string]: string}`.  And indexing into that type with `opt` of type `O`, widened to `string`, produces a value of type `string`:

```
const y: string = rec[opt]; // no error
```

Oops.  By widening both `O` and `R` to `string`, the compiler has inaccurately obliterated the distinction between the optional properties and the required properties.

---

As a workaround, I'd say that you could avoid this by doing a more accurate widening before the indexing.  If a value is assignable to an intersection `XXX & YYY`, then it is assignable to each of `XXX` and `YYY` separately.  The relevant part of `rect` for that line is the `Partial<Record<O, string>>` part, not the `Record<R, string>` part.  So let's widen to the relevant part first and see what happens:

```
const r: Partial<Record<O, string>> = rec; // okay
const x = r[opt];
// const x: Partial<Record<O, string>>[O]

wantString(x); // error!
// ------> ~
// string | undefined not assignable to string
```

Looks good.  We have widened `rec` to `r`, which succeeds.  Then the type of `r[opt]` is seen as `Partial<Record<O, string>>[O]`.  When the compiler widens *that* by plugging in `string` for `O`, it then gets `string | undefined` instead of `string`.  And you get the error you expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDqBLYALA8mYKD2AdgIYA2AzgDyZQQAe8BAJmVGcAE4oEDmANFACUa9CExZtOPAHxQAvACgoUAApF2uUhQEQAxnnaMq-CV25SZAMkG79hgcY6mpAbnnyAZgFcCO3ISgA7kQEwADKjjwAFPD0AFysEdwAlPEAbngojFAA3lAAvm5ePn4EUO4ATFTCDMwJknyC1aK1JtKReDjxmPzsuvFwiKgY2CWklN2CUilQ6Zk5bkp6BGxQAF5yUL06ANodwAC6zlAA9Mew8MhoWDj4xORGk9uY+4pQSysg8a3cG1u7OIcTmcCHgaOx2PpXu9gJt4qp1ChNNo9AYHt9zL9dEdTlA8ABrIggKGEFa0X7-A6uJQ46FQWhwtQaEhaGyoiboqRPF5KIIhcL1SK0JLYs4QcH6ACErxxAFo5fKZAA-aVnb5QAA+UG8jAg7i4ECyIJhRDIZBQ3GIACMSNBgKDvvICkA)